# Which Algorithm(s) can fit odds-effected racing, and how is that structured?

Tags: algorithms, supervised-learning, model-selection

I have data on horse racing, including 6 fetures for the race, and 27 features for each horse in the race - I also have the odds of the horse and whether it won or not for that race.

I am looking for a ML algorithm (or multiple - more ways of trying it the better) which firstly could support a varied number of horses per race such as this, (some races have as few as say 4 horses per race, some as many as 30), but also not to train it simply to find the most likely winner (That would be easy, one data feature on the horses if predicted odds, so picking the lowest value here would pretty much get a decent strike rate of picking a winner), but I want to be picking winners who would provide the most value. so for a given race, it might be a horse with expected odds of say 15, with some lower odds horses and some higher in the race, but this may be the best bet based on the likelyhood of that horse actaully winning.

I'm not sure how to train any model whilst taking into account the odds as well as the fact as whether they won or not as part of the supervised data.

Answer (score 0):

So you want your algorithm to pick a horse that is more likely to win than the odds would suggest in order to profit? The odds are set in a way such that, taking expert opinions and loads of data into account, the bookkeepers are minimising their expected losses. It seems unlikely that you have more information on the horses than they do, so I think it will be difficult to beat them at their own game!

Anyway, the approach I would take here would be to add a new feature into the data that looks at the horses position and odds in their most recent race(s):

$$
score = \frac{odds}{position}
$$

So, for example, say the odds for three particular horses and their corresponding positions in some race are as follows:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Predicted Odds} & \text{Actual Position} & \text{Score} \\ \hline
\text{Horse A} & 9:1   & 2 & 4.5 \\ \hline
\text{Horse B} & 1.3:1 & 1 &  1.3\\ \hline
\text{Horse C} & 3:1   & 6 & 0.5 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

This way, horses that are overperforming will have high scores, and horses that are underperforming will have low scores. You can average this score over the last $n$ races that the horse participated in to get a more stable scoring to evaluate the horses current form. This feature can then be used by any standard machine learning algorithm along with any other features you may have.

Comment: This is to be used with an exchange (Betfair) where the odds are pretty much a stock market situation. If ML can be applied to stocks then it should be similar here (just different parameters etc).

Also, bookies don't line their odds so much against the chance of the event happening, more against public opinion. They try to keep their book balanced to put themselves in win-win situations. I currently have a self-built (no libraries) genetic algorithm, parts of the data for this are form and odds etc. Thanks for this its given em some thoughts, still unsure of what I want to do next though

Comment: Fair comment about public opinion vs actual probabilities. Glad that I have given you some things to think about. Good luck!